# Give results in next column of predefined (but changing) words from text-cell

Tags: excel, vba, function, search

I have a chart with a text-column with numerous entries per cell.

- Entries are separated with **“;”**.
- Entries have the format “xy 00/00” (e.g. “AB 03/18”).

I need Excel to find and give in the next column a specific entry I predefine per row (above the column, example below).

- Only the first two and last two characters are defined, the characters in the middle can be whatever (e.g. “AB ??/18”).
- A cell can have more than one entry with the definition of “AB ??/18” (e.g. “AB 03/18” & “AB 08/18” etc.).

I need to know, if there are more than 1 of this predefined entries.
If I change the search box to “ZZ ??/12”, it should overwrite the previous defined search and give me back only the ZZ… ones.

For example:
Screenshot Chart
[image]

I tried a formula, but it gives me the first AB…, not the rest.

If it is only possible to give back the amount of the searched text in the cell above, that would also be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot doesn't seem entirely consistent with your objective, i.e.
the pattern AB ##/18 can be found 3 times in the string
*blabla WF 12/23; **AB 08/18**; **AB 09/18**; **AB 08/18***
but your count column registers only 1 result (for AB 08/18)- there is also a match in the 1st row (for AB 12/18), but there you have a count of 0...

The code below assumes that the 4 data cells from your screenshot are in the range A3:A6 and that **they are *not* part of a table**

```
Sub txtMatching()
    Dim results As String, cell As Range, incidence As Integer, pattern As String, pos As Integer, temp As String
    pattern = "AB ##/18"
    For Each cell In Range("A3:A6")
        pos = 1
        If cell.Value Like "*" & pattern & "*" Then
            Do
                pos = InStr(pos, cell.Value2, Mid(pattern, 1, InStr(1, pattern, "#") - 1))
                If pos = 0 Then Exit Do
                temp = Mid(cell.Value2, pos, Len(pattern))
                If temp Like pattern Then
                    results = results & temp & "; "
                    incidence = incidence + 1
                End If
                pos = pos + Len(pattern)
            Loop While pos < Len(cell.Value2)
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value2 = Array(Mid(results, 1, Len(results) - 2), incidence)
            results = vbNullString
            incidence = 0
        Else
            cell.Offset(0, 2).Value2 = 0
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey! First of all, Thank you!! It does work! I changed the screenshot, sorry It was late I miscounted and just put anything in there..

I changed the line ' pattern = "AB ##/18" ' to  ' pattern = Range("D2") ' (where the Info, I am looking for is written)

However, strangely it does only work with "AB ##/18". Meaning, if I change the value that is written in "D2", i get an Error in this line : ' temp = Mid(cell.Value2, pos, Len(pattern)) ' '[Runtime Error '5] 

Do you know what might be the cause? //Edit: this text looks weird, sorry.

Comment: It would help to know what the content of cell D2 is...
(it's probably to do with the first line after 'Do' as that line assigns to pos the position of the first 3 characters of pattern - the first 3 characters represent the constant portion of AB ##/18 so, with a different pattern, you may have to change from the number 3)

Comment: When I change "D2" to anything that doesn't start with "AB...", the runtime error occures. For example "WF ##/23". With anything "AB..." it does work, though. very strange ... :D

Comment: Ok, I've edited the code to make it more dynamic - give it a try

Comment: Yes!!!! Omg thank you!! This totally works!!  Tried it with different values and always get the correct answer displayed! Thank you so much for your time and effort, this will help me alot in future tasks with this chart.